# How to declare Internal table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how to define or declare Internal table in MySQL

I am new to MySQL and i Don't know the syntax

as you can see I create Stored Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MySP`(
    actioncode VARCHAR(5),
    TNewsID BIGINT
)

BEGIN

IF actioncode = 1 then -- Retrive all from the database --
    select *
    from emp.tbnews;
elseIF actioncode = 2 then -- Retrive all from the database By NewsID --
    select NewsID,NewsSubject,NewsSubjectAR,NewsDetails,NewsDetailsAR,CreatedOn,DisplayOrder,
           AllowDisplay,img  
    from emp.tbnews
    Where NewsID=TNewsID;
elseIF actioncode = 3 then -- fkjskldfjklsdf --
    select NewsID,NewsSubject,NewsSubjectAR,NewsDetails,NewsDetailsAR,CreatedOn,DisplayOrder,
           AllowDisplay,img  
    from emp.tbnews;

 END IF;
 END
```

What I Really want is to declare  Internal table before the IF Statement

in Sql Server I am doing it like this

```
declare  @tbTemp table (
 a as int,
 b as char...etc.
)
```

because i want to put insert statement after

```
IF actioncode = 1
    Insert into @tbTemp
```

so please if you know tell me how

best regards for every one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create temporary table tmp
(
id int unsigned not null,
name varchar(32) not null
)
engine=memory; -- change engine type if required e.g myisam/innodb

insert into tmp (id, name) select id, name from foo... ;

-- do more work...

select * from tmp order by id;

drop temporary table if exists tmp;
```

or

```
create temporary table tmp engine=memory select id, name from foo... ;

-- do more work...

select * from tmp order by id;

drop temporary table if exists tmp;
```

Comment: COOOOOOOOOL THANK YOU SO MUCH ,THAT IS SOLVE MY PROBLEM !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` ? It's an in-memory table specific to the connection running the statement so unless you are running persistent connections you have no worries on name conflicts.

Comment: Correction: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE does not denote that the table resides in memory. This is accomplished with the type=MEMORY appendum at the end of the creation statement. If you do not specify a type, the temporary table will be a MyISAM table. The only difference to a normal table will be that when the connection that ran the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE is closed, the temporary table is collected (it is scoped to the connection).