# Using with vs declare a temporary table: performance / difference?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a sql function in **SQLServer 2008** that declared a temporary table and uses it to compute a moving average on the values inside

```
declare @tempTable table 
    (
        GeogType nvarchar(5),
        GeogValue nvarchar(7),
        dtAdmission date,
        timeInterval int,
        fromTime nvarchar(5),
        toTime nvarchar(5),
        EDSyndromeID tinyint,
        nVisits int
    )
insert @tempTable select * from aces.dbo.fEDVisitCounts(@geogType, @hospID,DATEADD(DD,-@windowDays + 1,@fromDate),
                @toDate,@minAge,@maxAge,@gender,@nIntervalsPerDay, @nSyndromeID)


    INSERT @table (dtAdmission,EDSyndromeID, MovingAvg) 
    SELECT list.dtadmission
        , @nSyndromeID
        , AVG(data.nVisits) as MovingAvg
    from @tempTable as list 
        inner join @tempTable as data  
    ON list.dtAdmission between data.dtAdmission and DATEADD(DD,@windowDays - 1,data.dtAdmission) 
    where list.dtAdmission >= @fromDate
    GROUP BY list.dtAdmission
```

but I also found out that you can declare the tempTable like this:

```
with tempTable as 
(
    select * from aces.dbo.fEDVisitCounts('ALL', null,DATEADD(DD,-7,'01-09-2010'),
        '04-09-2010',0,130,null,1, 0)
)
```

**Question: Is there a major difference in these two approaches? Is one faster than the other or more common / standard?** I would think the declare is faster since you define what the columns you are looking for are.. Would it also be even faster if I were to omit the columns that were not used in the calculations of moving average?(not sure about this one since it has to get all of the rows anyways, though selecting less columns makes intuitive sense that it would be faster/less to do)

I also have found a `create temporary table @table` from here [How to declare Internal table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680886/how-to-declare-internal-table-in-mysql) but I don't want the table to persist outside of the function (I am not sure if the create temporary table does this or not.)

Comment: Here are two samples of running averages that don't require a temp table that you may wish to try for possible performance improvements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911326/sql-select-statement-for-calculating-a-running-average-column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618353/t-sql-calculate-moving-average

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `@table` syntax creates a table variable (an actual table in `tempdb`) and materialises the results to it.

The `WITH` syntax defines a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) which is not materialised and is just an inline View.

Most of the time you would be better off using the second option. You mention that this is inside a function. If this is a TVF then most of the time you want these to be inline rather than multi statement so they can be expanded out by the optimiser - this would instantly disallow the use of table variables.

Sometimes however (say the underlying query is expensive and you want to avoid it being executed multiple times) you might determine that materializing the intermediate results improves performance in some specific cases. There is [currently no way](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables) of forcing this for CTEs ([without forcing a plan guide at least](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/28/generating-xml-in-subqueries/))

In that eventuality you (in general) have 3 options. A `@tablevariable`, `#localtemp` table and a `##globaltemp` table. However only the first of these is permitted for use inside a function.

For further information regarding the differences between table variables and #temp tables [see here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386).

Comment: Mention also the #temp and ##temp table types for reference

Comment: @SQLMenace - Done but I've just noticed the OP is using this in a function so won't be able to use these...

Comment: so you can't use the # or ## inside of a function? and yes this is a TVF, what do you mean by them being inline? Just that the WITH syntax should be used?

Comment: @Mike - Yes. You get the error "Cannot access temporary tables from within a function." if you try. See this question for some explanation of the second point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554333/multi-statement-table-valued-function-vs-inline-table-valued-function

Answer (score 13):

In addition to what Martin answered

```
;with tempTable as 
(
    select * from aces.dbo.fEDVisitCounts('ALL', null,DATEADD(DD,-7,'01-09-2010'),
        '04-09-2010',0,130,null,1, 0)
)

SELECT * FROM tempTable
```

can also be written like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    select * from aces.dbo.fEDVisitCounts('ALL', null,DATEADD(DD,-7,'01-09-2010'),
        '04-09-2010',0,130,null,1, 0)
) AS tempTable  --now you can join here with other tables
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the with, I had thought it would do something similar to that but was not sure

Answer (score -1):

In addition,and correcting to Martin

The @table syntax creates a table variable IN MEMORY
The #Temp syntax creates a table variable in Tempdb

Thats why @tables are faster than #temp tables

Comment: I see you're new.  FYI this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: This is a myth. Whether or not an object is wholely in memory or in disk is related more to the amount of free memory you have. https://sqlperformance.com/2017/04/performance-myths/table-variables-in-memory

Comment: Use comment instead of posting it as answer