# Getting average salary of last 3 salaries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
+------------+--------+-----------+---------------+
|  paydate   | salary | ninumber  | payrollnumber |
+------------+--------+-----------+---------------+
| 2015-05-15 |   1000 | jh330954b |             6 |
| 2015-04-15 |   1250 | jh330954b |             5 |
| 2015-03-15 |    800 | jh330954b |             4 |
| 2015-02-15 |    894 | jh330954b |             3 |
| 2015-05-15 |    500 | ew56780e  |             6 |
| 2015-04-15 |   1500 | ew56780e  |             5 |
| 2015-03-15 |   2500 | ew56780e  |             4 |
| 2015-02-15 |   3000 | ew56780e  |             3 |
| 2015-05-15 |    400 | rt321298z |             6 |
| 2015-04-15 |    582 | rt321298z |             5 |
| 2015-03-15 |    123 | rt321298z |             4 |
| 2015-02-15 |    659 | rt321298z |             3 |
+------------+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

The above list is the data in my database. I need to get the average of the previous 3 salaries for each individual and output this.

I don't know where to begin with this so I cannot provide any of my working so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618353/t-sql-calculate-moving-average

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` to get the last three salaries in a subquery.  Then use `avg()`:

```
select ninumber, avg(salary)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ninumber order by payrollnumber desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by ninumber;
```

Comment: That's great as there is only 4 rows of data per entity. What happens if there are 6 rows of data for an entity?

Comment: @StarPilot the same thing will happen regardless of how many records there are per entity.